# Woocommerce create load more products with Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to create a function that loads more products using Ajax request in Woocommerce. My idea is to create a button "Load more Products" that replace the woocommerce pagination and that loads the 2nd the 3rd etc pages using ajax request. I've created the script that create the load more button with the ajax request and it works, but I'm trying to create a php function that retrive the rest of the products using the ajax request.

Below my code to create the load more button:

```
    <?php 

    $max_num_pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;

    if ($max_num_pages > 1) {
        $output .=
    '<script type="text/javascript">
    var page = 1,
    max_page = '.$max_num_pages.'
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".woocommerce-pagination").hide();
    jQuery("#woo_load_more").click(function(){
    jQuery(this).hide();
    jQuery("#spinner").show();
    jQuery.ajax({
         type: "POST",
        url: "http://demo.ecquadro.com/transport/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        data: {
            action: "wooPagination",
            page: page+1,
            per_page: 4,
        },
        success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
            page++;
             jQuery(".prova").append(data);
            jQuery("#spinner").hide();
            if (max_page > page) {
                 jQuery("#woo_load_more").show();
            }
         },
         error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
             jQuery("#spinner").hide();
             jQuery(this).show();
        }
        });
        });
        });
     </script>
     <div class="woo-products-load">
     <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="woo_load_more" class=""><span>'.__('Load More Posts', '').'</span></a>
     <img id="spinner" src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/img/loader.gif" style="display: none;">
     </div>';

     }

    echo $output;

    ?>
```

Any idea how to create a function called  "wooPagination" that load the rest of the pages?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you describe exactly what the issue is? What do have trouble with?
It's much easier to help if you know what to look for.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment.
I have 12 product in my demo store, 4 products per page. I want to create a function that load the 2nd and the 3rd page of products using ajax call.

You can see the script above in action here.

http://demo.ecquadro.com/transport/products 

As you can see the ajax call returns "0" value as I have problem to create the php function that loads the rest of products contained in the 2nd and 3rd page of my store.

Hope you can help me as I'm new with woocommerce.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The esiest solution would probably be to use the infinite-scroll script. You find it here http://www.infinite-scroll.com/

Make you do not delete the normal pagination from the HTML-output and then hook it up as follows(you probably need to change the selectors to fit your site):

```
var infinite_scroll = {
    loading: {
        //img: "/img/loading-animation.gif",
        msgText: '',
    },
    nextSelector: ".pagination a.next",
    navSelector: ".pagination",
    itemSelector: "#main-content ul.products .product-small",
    contentSelector: "#main-content ul.products"
};

//Unbind load more on scroll
$(window).unbind('.infscr');

//
$("#load-more-button").click( function() {
    $(document).trigger('retrieve.infscr');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort :-)

Comment: Hi,thanks for your answer. The solution works as I expected but I have an additional problem. I'm using Isotope jQuery for filtering products categories, but seems that the query works only for the first page loaded. Any idea how to refresh Isotope jQuery after ajax call? Thanks.

Comment: try adding this code  $container.isotope('insert',data);  after jQuery(".prova").append(data);